# Keynote 6.2 does not keep vector art as vector when copying from Keynote into Adobe Illustrator, is there a work around or setting to fix this?

Tags: macos, keynote

I used to copy vector art from Adobe Illustrator and paste this art into Keynote. It was possible to go in the reverse order as well, i.e., copy vector art in Keynote and paste it into Adobe Illustrator have have full editing function. Now when bringing vector art back into illustrator, the art is RASTERIZED.

Does anyone know of a workaround or setting that can correct this issue?

I am on a MacBook pro running OSX v10.9.3 Mavericks

Thank you,
-matt

Comment: iWorks '09 or iWorks '11? (iWorks '11 is the Mavericks upgrade.)